# Is there a way to get a box_shadow effect to overlap ALL nearby elements?

Tags: css, overlapping

I've created collapsible links for navigating my page.  All menu items in my navigation bar (vertical, nav div left floated) are also their own div (necessary for collapsing).  Each div is styled as a button with text.

I've used a light colored box_shadow with a relatively large blur radius for the :hover pseudo-element.  Now, when I hover over each button/div, it looks like the button/div is lit up (good) and the light spills out over the button/div above it (also good).  Unfortunately, the button/div below the one I am hovering over appears to be floating OVER the lit area (not so good).

Is there a way I can get the box_shadow styling to overlap both divs above and below the div the cursor is hovering over?  Other links in my site will not be affected, as the styling only applies to the divs and not to the links.

I'm 99% of the way to a perfect (IMO) design, but this one little issue seems to have no answer anywhere in the tutorials I normally use as a reference, or anywhere else for that matter.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrkYr/5/embedded/result/

Image:  http://desolosubhumus.webs.com/div%20overlap.jpg

Div CSS:

```
.mH { cursor: pointer; width: 110px; background-color: #A0522D; color: #000000; font-family: "DreamerOne","sans-serif"; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #fc9c47, 1px 1px 1px #fc9c47, 1px 1px 2px #300b00; border: 0 solid #210a02; border-radius: 1em; font-size: 0.9em; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; margin: 1px; box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 4px #210a02; }

.mH:hover { cursor: pointer; width: 110px; background-color: #F5A77F; font-family: "DreamerOne","sans-serif"; color: #c96914; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #210a02, 1px 1px 1px #210a02, 1px 1px 2px #000000; border: 0 solid #876e68; border-radius: 1em; font-size: 0.9em; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; margin: 1px; box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 4px #432c24, 1px 1px 35px 1px #D87824, -1px -1px 35px 1px #D87824; }
```

*Update:  Needing the vendor prefixes WAS a bug on my end.  I downloaded both browsers again and reinstalled, and now box-shadow and border-radius work on all four browsers (Safari just crashes when I navigate away from the default 'buy Apple stuff' page, or else I'd test it, too).  I'll update the CSS here and on Fiddle in just a sec.  G'bye cruft...

Comment: Can you please create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to look at? Also, you don't need vendor prefixes on `border-radius` and `box-shadow` anymore.

Comment: I've tested it on Opera, IE, FF, and Chrome (latest versions) and the styling does not appear to work on FF or Chrome without the vendor prefixes.  Perhaps this is a bug on my end.  I don't know what a fiddle is (other than a rustic name for a violin), but I'll look into that.

Comment: When creating fiddles, please try to make it a minimal example; make it as small as you possibly can while still demonstrating the issue.

Comment: The only part of the code that really has anything to do with the issue is posted in the OP.  The Fiddle does not include 99.9% of the content, or even half the code.  I even left out all but one script.  But for a minimal example, see the CSS for .mH and .mH:hover above.

Comment: And thank you to you too, anstosa.  With all the vendor tags, the CSS was getting quite messy.  I was hoping I could get rid of them soon, thinking that browser support for W3C standards was still too far behind the power curve in this area.  Much thanks for letting me know my browsers didn't download/install correctly and that I could start the clean-up already.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `z-index` to elevate it over the others, and `position: relative` to make it use the z-index.

For example, add to `.mH`, `position: relative` and to `.mH:hover`, `z-index: 100`.

End result: http://jsfiddle.net/nrkYr/6/

Comment: Perfect!  And it's such a tiny bit of code to add-much better than adding yet another script.  Thank you, much!